# Consistent Down votes on my profile

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Today I down voted a question on "StackOverflow" **for the first time**. The user I down voted had a reputation of 1(this means that this user can't take revenge even if it were offended). From that time onwards someone has been down voting the Questions I have asked and the answers I have given. Even the very old ones. Can this be a ripple of my Down Vote. How can I stop this guy or girl. I am quite worried.

Comment: Don't worry, it will be detected and reverted. Also, those 10 points will be compensated by one upvote on an answer.

Comment: Assuming it is the same person it will automatically be undone

Comment: All of the 5 downvotes seem to be within a 3 minute timespan, this should be caught by the scheduled task to revert serial downvoting but I'm not sure.

Comment: How long will it take to detect that it was a serial task by someone? And who would do that?

Comment: Someone got upset with you and feels that votig down makes sure you get the message. It wil get reverted at 03:00 UTC, if not flag one of your questions/answers for moderator attention and explain that the downvotes are due to a serial downvoter.

Comment: Ha!! I can't imagine that. I work so hard on my answers just to make sure I become a credible member of this platform. Anyhow thanks a lot for the explanation. I do appreciate your helping me @rene

Comment: I would suggest not starting answers with preaching about their asking habits. This (e.g. "I am assuming you are new to this. Personally I do feel that before turning up to this forum, a person should try code on his/her own." has nothing to do with the answer (it should be in a separate comment - the answer should just answer the question, not complain about it) and if the question shouldn't be answered, you shouldn't have answered it IMHO. I suspect this down-vote spree was triggered by something like this, rather than a down-vote (which people don't know you did, unless you told them).

Comment: What @AaronBertrand said above is exactly correct. Two wrongs don't make a right, but it's still expected that you be polite. And for the record, the offender has been warned and the votes will almost certainty be invalidated.

Comment: Absolutely @AaronBertrand It does sounds like a key to good reputation over here. Instead of giving away unwanted advices I should only focus towards the solution to the problem if it exists.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBarber I will give you an upvote one of your answers now for helping me!

Comment: @TalhaMasood please do not do that. It's not an appropriate reason to vote. Thank you for the thought, though; and you are welcome for the help.

Comment: @talha you are free to vote however you like, but technically, that is not how up-voting is supposed to work. :-)